# setcookie serialize array in php not working good

Tags: php, arrays, cookies, serialization, setcookie

**Hello** 
i want to save my array to same cookie 
after i serialize my array is look like:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"movie";i:4516;s:4:"date";s:10:"2017-12-23";}}
```

but when i try to insert this to my cookie its look like:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:\"movie\";i:4516;s:4:\"date\";s:10:\"2017-12-23\";}}
```

its add to this string / (i don't know why) and then i cannot unserialize()
the cookie to array.

i use PHP7 i don't know if its important
any help pleas?

Comment: As a work-around, could you use `str_replace` to get rid of the `\` before you unserialize?

Comment: this is not a mistake by php, its done because if we use many same type of quotes like this `"this is under string"while this is not"while this is inside"`, so to concatenate everything php use backslash (\) like javascript `"this is under string\"this also\"this also"`

Comment: so how can i get the unserialize from it? because now its return to me false

Comment: `stripslashes($yourstring)`

Comment: Do you mean *session*, rather than cookie? I don't see the point in passing serialized PHP to the front-end. If so, why are you trying to save a serialized string, rather than just saving the array and letting PHP handle it?

Comment: Thnak you very much stripslashes fixed the problem